# How to get firefox-esr on Tails to proxy to localhost?

Tags: firefox, proxy

***SETTING FIREFOX TO HTTP/HTTPS PROXY TO 127.0.0.1:8080 DOES NOT WORK PLEASE DO NOT SUGGEST THAT****

Running Tails 5.11 And Burpsuite Community

- Firefox-esr has a warning saying 'Connections to localhost, 127.0.0.1/8, and ::1 are never proxied'
- If I try to proxy to the local port Burpsuite is listening to (127.0.0.1:8080) I get 'proxy server is refusing connections
- If I try to use one of the other default IPs Burp can listen on, I'm blacklisted.

My main question is more about why in the world firefox-esr would have such a warning message, and how to get rid of it, but any other workarounds are greatly appreciated.

- Firefox/Burp on localhost = Proxy refusing connections
- Burp/Firefox on not localhost = Blacklisted IP
- Have also imported Portswiggers CA into firefox, so that isn't the source of the rejection from websites.

Burpsuite is set to use SOCKS5 on 9050 which I have verified is the tor port my machine is listening on.

***SETTING FIREFOX TO HTTP/HTTPS PROXY TO 127.0.0.1:8080 DOES NOT WORK PLEASE DO NOT SUGGEST THAT****

Answer (score 0):

Update: 'network.proxy.allow_hijacking_localhost' being set to true will get rid of the warning that localhost will never be proxied but doesn't change that fact that firefox just won't proxy.